# Getting a NoClassDefFoundError when going through Jena Permissions Example tutorial

Tags: java, jena

I tried to go through the example tutorial to add permissions to Apache Jena, using Fuseki, following:
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/permissions/example.html

After following all the steps when getting to the second time to start the server with `fuseki-server -config=run/config.ttl`
I get the following Java Error:

```
saphieron@plantlogger:~/semantic/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0 $ ./fuseki-server -config=run/config.ttl
    [2018-10-01 21:26:49] Server     INFO  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.8.0
    [2018-10-01 21:26:50] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/home/saphieron/semantic/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0
    [2018-10-01 21:26:50] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/home/saphieron/semantic/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0/run
    [2018-10-01 21:26:50] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///home/saphieron/semantic/apache-jena-fuseki-3.8.0/run/shiro.ini
    [2018-10-01 21:26:52] Config     INFO  Configuration file: run/config.ttl
    [2018-10-01 21:26:56] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/map/LRUMap
            at org.apache.jena.permissions.impl.SecuredItemImpl.incrementUse(SecuredItemImpl.java:210)
            at org.apache.jena.permissions.impl.SecuredItemInvoker.invoke(SecuredItemInvoker.java:117)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getGraph(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.DatasetImpl.<init>(DatasetImpl.java:67)
            at org.apache.jena.query.DatasetFactory.create(DatasetFactory.java:124)
            at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.createDataset(DatasetAssembler.java:60)
            at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
            at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:157)
            at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:144)
            at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:93)
            at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
            at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.getDataset(FusekiBuilder.java:120)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataServiceCustom(FusekiBuilder.java:73)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiBuilder.buildDataAccessPoint(FusekiBuilder.java:65)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.servicesAndDatasets(FusekiConfig.java:121)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.processServerConfigFile(FusekiSystem.java:266)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initServerConfiguration(FusekiSystem.java:237)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiSystem.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiSystem.java:207)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.serverInitialization(FusekiServerListener.java:96)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.server.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:53)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1514)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1476)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:273)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:449)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:416)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.start(JettyFuseki.java:137)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.runFuseki(FusekiCmd.java:372)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:356)
            at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
            at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
            at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:104)
            at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:67)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LRUMap
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 50 more
```

The web front end seems to have loaded, but actually nothing other than the index.html seems to be accessible. My question mainly is, if that is all that is supposed to happen, or if that `NoClassDefFoundError` is supposed to happen, when following the tutorial. I was expecting some kind of user/pw dialog, and not being able to access any data on from the endpoint.
Now because I don't get any info whether any access failed because I didn't authenticate myself or the server never started properly I am not sure how to continue from here.

Tried this with:

- Jena Fuseki 3.8.0
- commons-collections4-4.2
- jena-permissions-3.8.0.jar
- jena-permissions-3.8.0-example.jar
- java version "1.8.0_65"

Comment: I'm assuming this is a WAR application?  Is it bundled in an EAR?  When it's deployed - I'd check whats being put in the Lib folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JVM can't find the `LRUMap` class, which is part of **Apache Commons Collections v4**. Please double check the steps that mention that library:

> 4. Download the Apache Commons Collections v4 http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi Uncompress the commons-collections*.jar into the Fuseki Home directory.

And on Linux/Unix...

> change MyCode.jar to permissions.jar:example.jar:commons-collections*.jar

Or if you use Windows...

> Change MyCustomCode.jar to permissions.jar;example.jar;commons-collections*.jar

**Note**: you should replace the `*` in the lines above with the version number. So you should use `commons-collections4-4.2.jar` instead.

```
permissions.jar:example.jar:commons-collections4-4.2.jar
```

or

```
permissions.jar;example.jar;commons-collections4-4.2.jar
```

Comment: It was specifically the * in commons-collections*.jar in the fuseki-server file. I guess I was assuming that the with the * it would take the first fitting .jar file in the folder. Considering that the error was in a classdef not found instead of the .jar not being found made it kinda confusing for me.